# Javascript - double quotes in variable

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create html tags dynamically using javascript. Please refer to below code.

```
function getPhotosSuccess(data) {

    if (data.d.results.length > 0) {

        var response = data.d.results;
        var innerhtml = "";

        $.each(response, function(key, value) {
            var newItem = '<div class="item"><div class="well"><a href="' + value.ServerRelativeUrl + '" data-lightbox="roadtrip" data-title="' + value.ListItemAllFields.Image_x0020_Description + '"><img class="img-responsive" src="' + value.ServerRelativeUrl + '" alt=""></a></div><div><p>' + value.ListItemAllFields.Image_x0020_Description + '</p></div></div>';
            innerhtml += newItem;
        });

        $("#masonryPicGallery .row:eq(0)").html(innerhtml);

    } else {

        console.log("empty response from server"); 
    }
}
```

My problem is, here variable `value.ListItemAllFields.Image_x0020_Description` contains a string that starts with double quote.

So my html renders as following -->

[image]

Can anybody please help me out with this scenario.

Comment: You should use the DOM API to create elements, instead of concatenating strings and dumping them into the DOM. `document.createElement('div')` and so on. Yes, it's much more verbose than a few HTML snippets, but it doesn't suffer from syntax issues as you're dealing with.

Comment: _always_ try to avoid using string concatenation to build elements

Comment: @deceze Sure, I will try to use DOM API for this. Thanks....

Comment: Given you've got `data-*` attributes and it looks like you're using Lightbox too, I wonder if you're already using jQuery which would make the DOM creation a lot simpler

Comment: @Alnitak Yes I am using jQuery to iterate over the response object that I am getting from the server and then to create a dynamic html from the received data.

Comment: @RohitWaghela did my answer below not work? Can you try it and share what happens?

Comment: @CaptainStack no, your answer won't work - it'll still create imbalanced quotes even with the ES6 string template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using jQuery (and the presence of Lightbox attributes in your snippet suggests you are) you can use that to avoid using unreliable string concatenation to build your elements:

```
// create DOM entries without variables
var $newItem = $('<div class="item"><div class="well"><a data-lightbox="roadtrip"><img class="img-responsive" alt=""></a></div><div><p></p></div></div>');

// then populate the appropriate fields using jQuery DOM traversal
$newItem.find('a').attr({
     'href': value.serverRelativeUrl,
     'data-title': value.ListItemAllFields.Image_x0020_Description
   }).find('img')
     .attr('src', value.ServerRelativeUrl);

$newItem.find('p').text(value.ListItemAllFields.Image_x0020_Description);
```

Comment: Thanks..I will try your answer. And I will mark as answer if it works..:)

Comment: It's untested, of course, but it _should_ mostly do the job, even if it needs some very minor tweaking to get the DOM traversal correct

Comment: Alnitak, I am iterating over the object, so there will be multiple `<div class="item">`.. So I will not be able to identify which item i need to update.. I have updated my question accordingly..

Comment: That's fine - just put the above code inside the `.each` loop.  The above code does everything relative to the newly created item so the fact that's multiple items doesn't matter.

Comment: and don't use `+=` to append the new content to the DOM, just do: `$("#masonryPicGallery .row:eq(0)").append($newItem)` inside the loop

Comment: Thanks a lot... this worked for me. However there is only minor change as below snippet -- `$newItem.find('a').attr({
     'href': value.ServerRelativeUrl,
     'data-title': value.ListItemAllFields.Image_x0020_Description
   })`

Comment: @RohitWaghela yup, minor typo introduced from when I change from having a separate call to `.attr` for each attribute to the current version with the object containing two attributes.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you should just have to remove the double quotes that come just before the single quotes since those are included in the variable anyway. So like this:

```
var newItem = '<div class="item"><div class="well"><a href="' + value.ServerRelativeUrl + '" data-lightbox="roadtrip" data-title=' + value.ListItemAllFields.Image_x0020_Description + '><img class="img-responsive" src="' + value.ServerRelativeUrl + '" alt=""></a></div><div><p>' + value.ListItemAllFields.Image_x0020_Description + '</p></div></div>';
```

If you're able to use ES6 or Babel (which transpiles ES6 into older JavaScript for older browswers) you can also use string templates, which use backticks (left of the '1' key) instead of quotes:

```
var newItem = `<div class="item"><div class="well"><a href="${value.ServerRelativeUrl}" data-lightbox="roadtrip" data-title="${value.ListItemAllFields.Image_x0020_Description}"><img class="img-responsive" src="${value.ServerRelativeUrl}" alt=""></a></div><div><p>${value.ListItemAllFields.Image_x0020_Description}</p></div></div>`;
```

Comment: this won't work - it completely fails to account for quotation marks _inside_ the substituted strings